# Erro Android Studio - compilar app direto para aparelho

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando executar o comando para compilar um app direto do cmd para celular, porem estou caindo em uma expection, preciso de ajuda:

Codigo que estou executando é

```
react-native run-android
```

Obs.: Eu plugo o meu celular (ja deixei o modo depuração usb ativo), abro o prompt de comando e digito esse comando acima, aparece o seguinte erro:

Failure: Build failed with an exception.
*What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

Comment: Olhando a msg ele diz que não tem celular conectado, você poder tentar verificar se na ferramenta que você esta usando não está faltando os drives adb ou até mesmo os drives do seu celular instalados no computador.

Comment: Eu consegui identificar, eu não tinha o driver da samsung, apos instalar consegui fazer o build. Obrigado @RogersMarques.